# Python pandas: substitute missing values within a time series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time-series

I am currently working on a routine to process meteodata from different weatherstations. Unfortunetly there is missing data from time to time. I wrote a routine to merge data from all stations into a dataframe and implemented a "NaN_Flag" column which shows missing data of a certain timepoint.

Now the plan is to fill those data gaps with data of a nearby station. For temperature and humidity interpolation would be possible but depending on size of the gap not really ideal.
For rain events interpolation wouldnt make any sense.

The first column is the index column containing date,time and location. Now I am looking for a solution to fill in meassured data of another location (same time) if the "NaN_Flag" shows "1".

So in the following simplified example I would like that the dataset of 01-01-01 00:20:00 of Location1
is automaticly replaced with data of the same datetime ofLocation2. So every Location has a "backup"-Location and everytime the "NaN_Flag" shows "1" data is automaticly replaced with the the appropriate backup data.
Anyone got any idea how to accomplish that?

```
DATETIME_UTC_LOCATION           DATETIME_UTC              LOCATION    TEMP   PLUV   HUM   NaN_FLAG 
2020-01-01 00:00:00 Location1   2020-01-01 00:00:00       Location1   5.25   0.0    87.3  0
2020-01-01 00:10:00 Location1   2020-01-01 00:10:00       Location1   6.12   0.1    85.0  0
2020-01-01 00:20:00 Location1   2020-01-01 00:20:00       Location1                       1
2020-01-01 00:00:00 Location2   2020-01-01 00:00:00       Location2   5.12   0.0    88.9  0
2020-01-01 00:10:00 Location2   2020-01-01 00:10:00       Location2   6.25   0.1    84.3  0
2020-01-01 00:20:00 Location2   2020-01-01 00:20:00       Location2   6.75   0.2    82.5  0
```

Comment: from a scientific perspective, don't you think that adapting values of nearby stations would introduce a statistical bias? or asked differently: why is leaving the missing values as NaN *not* an option?

Comment: You are definetly right about the statistical bias. Yet the problem ist that I am feeding this data into different Disease simulation models and some of them are not capable to handle gaps longer than one hour and just stop running. Therefore introducing a bias is less problematic. Further I also have Locations with 2 weatherstation at the same location and also additional algorithm generated data which could act as a more or less relicable backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dataframe you have has an equivalent format to this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'month': ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Jan","Feb","Mar"],
                        'station': ["station_1","station_1","station_1","station_2","station_2","station_2"],
                        'values': [3.2, np.nan, 4.1, 3.6, 5.8, 4.2]}).set_index('month')
```

output:

```
              station   values
    month       
    Jan       station_1    3.2
    Feb       station_1    NaN
    Mar       station_1    4.1
    Jan       station_2    3.6
    Feb       station_2    5.8
    Mar       station_2    4.2
```

You can use:

```
df.loc[df['station'] == "station_1"] = df.loc[df['station'] == "station_1"].fillna(df.loc[df['station'] == "station_2"])
```

to substitute NaN values of the station 1 for the station 2 equivalent values. By "equivalent" I mean matching in the "month" index.

Output:

```
              station   values
    month       
    Jan       station_1    3.2
    Feb       station_1    5.8
    Mar       station_1    4.1
    Jan       station_2    3.6
    Feb       station_2    5.8
    Mar       station_2    4.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Currently all different locations are in the same csv/dataframe. But splitting wouldnt be an issue if theres no other option. Currently the index is datetime_location. Your solution would work if I create a dataframe of each location where datetime is the index and I insert the location column after missing data is replaced. Anyway if someone came up with a way to make it work within the merged dataframe I would prefere that.

Comment: Ah all right I believe I understand. In that case you can do the substitution of NaN values in a column for values in another column like this:



df.column_with_nans.fillna(df.column_second_station, inplace=True)



where, as the names say, "column_with_nans" is the name of the column with missing values and "column_second_station" is the column with values from a nearby station.

Comment: No sorry, maybe I explained it wrong. Like you see in my example dataframe. datetime,location, temperature,humidity....are in different columns and the timeseries of the different locations are in rows.

Comment: Yes you're totally right, I edited my answer so there's no need to create new dataframes by using a (kinda long) one-liner, let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...wasnt able to get to it earlier. Yes it seem to work perfectly. Thank you very much!